# Relaciones Entity Framework uno a muchos o muchos a muchos

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

Tengo una duda, sobre si esta es una relacion uno a muchos o muchos a muchos. Estas son mis dos entidades:

Usuario

- Id
- Nombre

Estudios

- Id
- Titulo

Yo se que un usuario puede tener uno o mas estudios y un estudio puede tener mas de un usuario. Estoy casi seguro que es una relacion muchos a muchos, pero no se si asi seria como lo deberia codificar para que Entity Framework lo reconozca con Code First en C#

```
public class Estudio
{
    public int EstudioID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public List<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
 public class Usuario
{
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }      
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Estudio> Estudios { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Lo has probado?. Has probado a realizar una migración Inicial y un ' UpdateDatabase` para ver que tablas te crea en la BD?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que **EF Code First** cree correctamente las tablas correspondientes y las relaciones entre ellas, debes definir en el contexto de datos las relaciones entre tus tablas principales, además de la **tabla intermedia** de **muchos a muchos** **`UsuariosEstudios`**.

Para ello, debes sobrescribir el método **`OnModelCreating`** de tu **DbContext**, e incluir en lo que se llama "Fluent Api" la estructura que EF debe crear en la BD.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Estudios)
            .WithMany(t => t.Usuarios)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UsuariosEstudios");
                m.MapLeftKey("UsuarioID");
                m.MapRightKey("EstudioID");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Como ves, hemos relacionado las tablas `Estudio` y `Usuario` a través de sus **claves primarias**, y además hemos indicado que se cree la tabla **`UsuariosEstudios`** donde se establecerán las relaciones de "código a código".

---

***Nota:*** En este [Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=41&v=9chTaFuaBcU) podrás ver un ejemplo exactamente igual al tuyo, donde se explica con todo detalle como configurar el "Fluent Api" para una relación de "muchos a muchos".